# Пропуск директории/файла, если к нему нет доступа, или случилась любая другая ошибка (D)

Tags: d

Есть такой код:

```
import std.file;
import std.exception;


void listdir(string dirpath) {
    foreach(string fname; dirEntries(dirpath, SpanMode.depth, false))
     {
         try {
            if (fname.isDir)
                listdir(fname);
            writeln(fname);
         }
         catch (Throwable) {
             continue;
         }
    }
}

void main() {
    listdir("/");
}
```

Проблема в том, что исполнение прекращается на любой ошибке. Можно ли пропускать директории и файлы при возникновении ошибки, не прекращая исполнение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решено: надо поменять SpanMode.depth на SpanMode.shallow